# NSUrlErrorDomain can't find the code and how to deal with it anywhere

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

This is the error code I'm getting when I try to pull data from a server, while debugging on my device through Xcode.

> error NSError?    domain: "NSURLErrorDomain" - code: 4294966274   0x15d9ae90

What does it mean? How I solve it?

I found this site with a list of enums
https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/foundation_constants/1508628-url_loading_system_error_codes

But it doesn't give numbers only the enum strings.

Comment: Are you using `http` or `https` url?

Comment: Explain about the Error in detail. Are you using any NSUrlRequest?

Comment: I'm using http url

Comment: this is the NSUrlRequest         let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) in

Comment: just to be clear, when running on a phone not debugging through xcode, the NSUrlRequest works perfectly fine. It only happens while debugging through XCode